# libGDX OpenGL clear buffer bit

Tags: java, libgdx

I like the effect of not clearing the buffer bit how it creates a ghost trail and it allows me to create neat effects and images. Is there a way I can capture and save somehow the drawing on the screen? Perhaps to recall in code later.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a FrameBuffer.
In your loading code you would have something like:

```
FrameBuffer fbo;
public void load() {
    int screenwidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    int screenheight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB8888, screenwidth, screenheight, false);
}
```

and in your rendering code:

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    fbo.begin();
    batch.begin();
    //rendering stuff goes here
    batch.end();
    fbo.end();
}
```

now to get the Texture of the FrameBuffer for later reuse:

```
fbo.getColorBufferTexture()
```